# Embedding a Google Doc in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I've developed a rather complex Google Sheets and hoping to embed user documentation directly into the Google Sheets. While I can certainly write the documentation directly in Google Sheets, I'd prefer to do it in a Google Document (The Word-like clone, just to be clear) and embed in the Google Sheet.

Some kind of onOpen script would be great if there is no native solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add a menu to your spreadsheet where a user can choose **Show instructions**.

---

First, add the code below into the appropriate files in the code editor from your spreadsheet.

**Tools** > **Script editor**

[image: Project example]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {

    SpreadsheetApp
        .getUi()
        .createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Show instructions', 'showInstructions')
        .addToUi();
}

function showInstructions() {

    var html = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('instructions')
        .setWidth(1500)
        .setHeight(800);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, ' ');
}
```

---

You'll have **Code.gs** to start with. Here's how to add **instructions.html**.

[image: How to add HTML file]

**instructions.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <iframe width="1050" height="550" style="border: 0" src="COPIED_LINK_HERE?embedded=true&widget=false&chrome=false&headers=false"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Follow the steps in the image below to obtain your URL.

Then paste that URL in **instructions.html** where the text `COPIED_LINK_HERE` is.

You may have to play with the `height` and `width` values in both to make it fit your needs.

[image: Instructions]